# how to attach a file in a response from web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aurelia, closedxml

I need to generate a Excel file in my webAPI in ASP.NET Core with the data received from a aurelia web app. The flow is this:
In frontend I make the request

```
Print(printData: PrintData) {
return this.http
  .fetch(`planning/Print`, {
    method: "post",
    body: json(printData)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

In web API Controller I get the data and generate the Excel file using the ClosedXML library

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Print")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Print([FromBody] PrintDataVM data)
{      

  var getResponse = await mediator.Send(new PrintPlanning(data));

  return Ok(getResponse);

public async Task<XLWorkbook> PrintPlanning(PrintDataVM data)
  {
    using (XLWorkbook workBook=new XLWorkbook())
    {
      var workSheet= workBook.Worksheets.Add("Horas");

       workSheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hola";

      return workBook;    
    }
```

In my controller getResponse is this
[image: getResponse]

[image: getResponse]

and here my doubts begin because I don't know if I should get this obtejct or a memorystream. I do not know how to make the frontend get this so that once received I can treat it there. 
Right now this gives me error obviously

Any idea please?

Regards

[image: error fetch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your file to stream and return file

```
var getResponse = await mediator.Send(new PrintPlanning(data));

var ms = new MemoryStream();
getResponse.SaveAs(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
return File(ms, "application/octet-stream", "filename");
```

or use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` instead of `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension to simplify things: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML.Extensions.WebApi/

### Usage

In your WebApi controller define an action that will generate and download your file:

```cs
public class ExcelController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/file/{id}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        var wb = await BuildExcelFile(id);
        return wb.Deliver("excelfile.xlsx");
    }

    private async Task<XLWorkbook> BuildExcelFile(int id)
    {
        //Creating the workbook
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");
            ws.FirstCell().SetValue(id);

            return wb;
        });

        return await t;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: First of all, congratulations on your work. I understand that with this extension you don't need to do this https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Deliver-an-Excel-file-in-ASP.NET

Comment: The link you mention is specifically for ASP.NET Webforms, not WebApi. But, yes, if you use the extension, then you will not need this kind of boilerplate code.

Comment: With the Excel generated in webAPI and received in my FrontEnd web app I need to generate a File or a Blob to download it. I have generated the File and a tag <a> to download the file but when I open it I get a format error. The response received has Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet and Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Planificacion.xlsx and the file downloaded is Planificacion.xlsx. If I save the file generated in the code in WebAPI works fine

Comment: I see that with deliver method in the response received the content-length does not exist

Comment: Please log an issue on the Github page of you believe it is a bug.